# $f,g:\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R$ are nonzero linear maps. Then which are true?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

> [image]
>
> (A) is wrong: Consider $f:(x,y,z)\mapsto(x,0,0),~g:(x,y,z)\mapsto(x,y,0)$
>
> (B) is wrong: Consider $f:(x,y,z)\mapsto(x,0,0),~g:(x,y,z)\mapsto(x,y,0)$
>
> (C) is wrong: $\ker g$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$ and let $f:\ker g\to\mathbb R$ be the restriction of $f.$ Then since $\ker f\subset\ker g$ by isomorphism theorem $\ker g /\ker f\simeq\Im(f)\ne\mathbb R.$
>
> (D) is correct.

Please tell me if I'm right. I'm skeptical especially about (C).

Comment: None of your functions are maps to $\mathbb{R}$, they are back to $\mathbb{R}^3$.  However the answer is indeed D.

Comment: @vadim123 Shouldn't (B) be the correct answer?

Comment: @Amitesh, oops you're right, I missed the "nonzero" part.

Comment: (A) is funny: "Let $f, g \colon \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ be _non-zero_ linear maps ... Then $f = g = 0$."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$f,g:\mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}$ are required to be non-zero linear maps **into** $\mathbb{R}$ so your counterexamples for (A) and (B) (in particular, the map $g:\mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}^2$) are not valid.

The key point is to use the rank-nullity theorem to note that $\text{ker}(f)$ and $\text{ker}(g)$ are two-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^3$ with one contained in the other; what does this imply?

I hope this helps!

Comment: So, any non zero linear map (over $\mathbb{R}$) $f: V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is surjective??? I did not realize this before... :)

Comment: $f: \mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a "non zero" linear map....

applying rank nullity theorem, we see that 

$Rank(f) + Dim(ker(f)) = Dim(V)=3$

$Rank(f)$ is dimension of image of $f$ in $\mathbb{R}$. 

As $f$ is non zero map, its image would be non zero subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ which have to be equal to $\mathbb{R}$

Thus, $Rank(f) =1$. So, $Dim(ker(f))=2$ similarly $Dim(ker(g))=2$

$ker(f)\subseteq ker(g)$. 

But, a subspace can not "properly contain"  another subspace having "same dimension" 

So this would imply $ker(f)=ker(g)$